# How to expand/collapse a row when user clicked on it in angular datatable?

Tags: angular

I have this code but it is expanding all the rows when I clicked on the row and it is not collapsed when I clicked on it

in html file
`code`

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let custmodel of customerbasemodel; index as i">
    <tr  role="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-parent="#accordion" (click)="expand()"
    aria-expanded="true" class="collapsed bg"
    aria-controls="services"
    [title]="'Entity Unq Id: ' +custmodel.entityUnqId + ', Entity Type: '+ custmodel.entityType" *ngIf="custmodel.phoneList.length>1 ||custmodel.phone1List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.phone2List.length>1 ||  custmodel.phone3List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.phone4List.length>1 ||custmodel.emailList.length>1 || 
    custmodel.email1List.length>1 || custmodel.email2List.length>1 || 
    custmodel.email3List.length>1 || custmodel.email4List.length>1 || 
    custmodel.addressList.length>1 || custmodel.address5List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.address2List.length>1 || custmodel.address3List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.address4List.length>1 ||custmodel.pincodeList.length>1 ||
    custmodel.pincode1List.length>1 || custmodel.pincode2List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.pincode3List.length>1 ||custmodel.pincode4List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.distList.length>1 ||custmodel.dist1List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.dist2List.length>1 ||custmodel.dist3List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.dist4List.length>1 || custmodel.bankAcctNoList.length>1 ||
    custmodel.bankAcctNo1List.length>1 ||custmodel.bankAcctNo2List.length>1 ||
    custmodel.bankAcctNo3List.length>1 ||custmodel.bankAcctNo4List.length>1; else other">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let property of propertiesList">
        <td>
            <!-- <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#accordion{{i}}" aria-expanded="true"
                aria-controls="services"> -->
            <div class="bg">
                <div class="bg" *ngIf="property.indexOf('address') >-1 || property.indexOf('phone') >-1 ||
                    property.indexOf('email') >-1 || property.indexOf('dist') >-1 ||
                    property.indexOf('bank_account_no') >-1 ||
                    property.indexOf('pincode') >-1; else normal1" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <h6 *ngFor="let address of custmodel[property] | slice:0:1">
                        {{address}}
                    </h6>
                    <div id="accordion{{i}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="servicesheading">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <h6 *ngFor="let address of custmodel[property] | slice:1">
                                {{address}}
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ng-template #normal1>
                    <div class="bg">
                        {{custmodel[property]}}
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </div>
            <!-- </a> -->
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

in ts file

```html
expand(){
$('.collapse').collapse();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to pass the index of the row you are expanding like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let custmodel of customerbasemodel; index as i">
    <tr  role="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
    data-parent="#accordion" (click)="expand(i)"...
```

Then in `ts` file set your logic to expand/collapse only the row with provided index.